# Cisco E1/T1 Time Slot

Tags: networking, cisco, t1

What is exactly the Cisco's E1/T1 time slot?

How do I configure them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time slots are inherent to the (channelised) E1/T1 transmission method. An E1 has 32 time slots. One is used as a clock and is not usable for sending payload (this is, I believe, time slot 0). When used as an ISDN30 link, the E1 also has one time slot (slot 15) dedicated as a control channel (running Q.921 and Q.931 for ISDN signaling), but when used for data transfer, this is normally available for payload.

It is configured in a way similar to this (I shall happily assume that you have a channelised E1 controller in slot 0/0 for the purposes of the example):

```
controller E1 0/0
 description The E1 controller
 ! you'll need relevant timing and framing to be configured, ask your ISP
 channel-group 0
  timeslots 1-2
 channel-group 1
  timeslots 3-7

interface serial0/0:1
 description This is the interface corresponding to channel-group 1
interface serial0/0:2
 description And this is the interface corresponding to channel-group 2
```